# Encrypt file in PHP, decrypt in .Net?

Tags: php, .net, encryption

I need to develop an add-on to a PHP web application which encrypts and uploads files to an FTP location.

I then need to write a separate .Net app which will allow a user that has manually downloaded the files from the FTP location to decrypt the file so that it can then be used locally.

I am aware that there are a large number of different options for encryption in PHP and .Net, but am not sure which - if any - are compatible.

At the moment if someone could just point me in the direction of the methods/functions/libraries to use, I would be very grateful. I don't necessarily need all the code to do it just yet, I can probably work that out myself, although of course, if someone is feeling generous or super helpful and can give me that too, then I'm not going to complain...! :-)

Hoping someone can help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the encryption just for protecting the file while its going between servers?  If that is the case then use sftp or which in encrypted. Then you can probably use https for downloading, which is also encrypted.

Comment: Unfortunately SFTP is not available in the FTP farm I am using. An option (though not an ideal one) may be to switch FTP providers, but encryption has other benefits too.

Comment: ftp over ssh even?  I would change providers if there is no encryption methods at all.  If you've seen how easy it is for someone to steal your password over an unencrypted channel you would want encryption

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a popular algorithm such as RSA, DES, Blowfish, etc.

Many (most?) popular encryption algorithms are supported by the PHP [Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) extension

Comment: Great, yes, this is what I was thinking. I just wasn't sure if there were any cross platform compatibility issues. I guess I will give it a go and see how/if it works!